# Sequence of running code in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is a part of my code:

```
$.post('category.php',{datatosend : datatosend},result);

function result(data) {
    $('#placeHolder').append('<select onchange="loadcats();" id="categoryPID" name="categoryPID" >').append(data).append('</select>');  
    alert($('#placeHolder').html());
    });
}
```

and I want to have this HTML in alert:

```
<select onchange="loadcats();" id="categoryPID" name="categoryPID">
<option value="37">computer</option><option value="38">mobile</option>
</select>
```

but the result is:

```
<select onchange="loadcats();" id="categoryPID" name="categoryPID"></select>
<option value="37">computer</option><option value="38">mobile</option>
```

why and what should I do?! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This comes up quite a lot, and it's due to a misunderstanding of what the `.append()` function does. People seem to get the impression that it's the same as concatenating HTML strings to the `innerHTML` property of the selected element(s), but it's not.

The `.append()` function works with actual DOM elements. If you pass in a string then it will parse that as HTML, create the elements, and then append those to the selected element(s). So when you do this:

```
$('#placeHolder').append('<select onchange="loadcats();" id="categoryPID" name="categoryPID" >')
```

It creates the entire `<select>` element (it doesn't care that you didn't close the tag, it does it for you), then appends that to `#placeHolder`. Then when you call `.append(data)`, it again creates the option elements, then appends those *after the `<select>`*.

The best idea would be to create the `<select>` element individually, add the `<option>` elements to that, then append it to `#placeHolder`:

```
// create the entire <select> element
var select = $('<select onchange="loadcats();" id="categoryPID" name="categoryPID" >');
// append the <option> elements to it
select.append(data);
// append the <select> to #placeHolder
$('#placeHolder').append(select);
// then finally alert its HTML
alert($('#placeHolder').html());
```

It would actually be possible to chain the majority of those calls but I've split it out purely for the purposes of illustrating what's happening. The chained version would look something like this:

```
alert($('#placeHolder').append($('<select onchange="loadcats();" id="categoryPID" name="categoryPID" >').append(data)).html());
```

Comment: @MeToo The whole point is that you don't need to. It's **not** HTML, it's a DOM element - it's already ended the moment it has been created.

Comment: @MeToo Great, glad I could help. If it was useful you might want to consider accepting it as the answer (click the tick mark to the left of the answer).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#placeHolder').append('<select onchange="loadcats();" id="categoryPID" name="categoryPID" >');
$('#categoryPID').append(data);
```

Comment: thanks for your reply but i didn't mean that. i have a div that its id is placeHolder and i want to append the html codes to that

Comment: @MeToo jQuery doesn't append HTML code, though, it appends DOM elements; see my answer for the full explanation. As far as I can tell the code here would give you the result you want.