# jQuerys wrap function wrap works quite odd

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I stumbled over jQuery's wrap() function.

Somehow it behaves different when I'm trying to wrap two div tags which have some text in between them, than without text between the two divs.

jquery:

```
var wrapper1 = '<div class="wrap1">something in between<div class="innerwrap1">';
$('.content1').wrap(wrapper1);    
var wrapper2 = '<div class="wrap2"><div class="innerwrap2">';
$('.content2').wrap(wrapper2);
```

The resulting HTML is this:

```
<div class="wrap1">
    something in between
    <div class="innerwrap1"></div>  <!-- wtf? -->
    <div class="content1">Lorem</div>
</div> 
<div class="wrap2">
    <div class="innerwrap2">
        <div class="content2">Ipsum</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's a fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/RfJN5/

The first result is quite surprising, isn't it? I would think that both closing divs should be placed after .content1, no matter if theres any text between the divs.

Of course I know it's safer to add the closing divs myself to control the behaviour, but is this some kind of bug or just a missunderstanding of how to use jQuery wrap?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're using invalid markup in your html generation code. Expect unexpected results. **Different browsers will interpret the invalid markup differently.**

Comment: Like many other people you're completely misunderstanding how these functions work. I've covered it in reasonable detail for `.append()` [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15810067/sequence-of-running-code-in-jquery), a lot of the same ideas hold for `.wrap()`.

Comment: @AnthonyGris you help me understanding that these kind of functions parse the given string to create DOM Elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

that works as expected, your `wrapper1` would be the main object that would be wrapped around `content1` and as you haven't closed the `innerwrapper1`, jquery closes it for you.  If you want to wrap with inner wrapper then make this an object, wrap content and then append the inner wrapper to wrapper:

```
var wrapper1 = $('<div class="wrap1">something in between</div>'),
    innerWrapper = $('<div class="innerwrap1" />');

$('.content1').wrap(innerWrapper);    
wrapper1.append($('.innerwrap1'));
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/tD9MM/3/)